# Redux Saga is not triggering when action type is dispatched

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, saga

I've implemented Redux-saga for the first time. I followed the documentation to create the saga.

The problem is Saga isn't triggering when the action type is dispatched. Let me elaborate a little.
I have a saga.js file that contains the watcher and worker saga in it. The root-saga.js just combines all the different sagas. The store.js file contains the basic setup code for the configuration for the sagas.

I'm dispatching the action type on a useEffect call in a component. The redux dev tool shows the action type is called correctly. Please have a look at the code.

The expected outcome is, the saga should automatically get called when the action type function is dispatched. The corresponding console logs should be shown.

Edit 1: Action definitions code are added

// store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import rootReducer from './reducers/root-reducer';
import rootSaga from './sagas/root-saga';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
  )
);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```

// root-saga.js

```
import { all, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import { dashboardSagas } from './dashboard-sagas';

function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([call(dashboardSagas)]);
}

export default rootSaga;
```

// saga.js page

```
import { takeLatest, put, call, all } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import axios from 'axios';

import { DASHBAORD } from '../types/dashboard';
import { DashboardSuccess, DashboardFail } from '../actions/dashboard';
import { APIS_ENDPOINTS } from '../../util/api-endpoints';

// watcher saga

export function* fetchDashboardSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(DASHBAORD.START, fetchDashboardAsyncSaga);
}

// worker saga

function* fetchDashboardAsyncSaga() {
  yield console.log('123');
  try {
    const resp = yield axios.get(APIS_ENDPOINTS.DASHBOARD);
    yield console.log(resp);
    yield put(DashboardSuccess(resp));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    yield put(DashboardFail('Something went wrong. Please try again'));
  }
}


export function* dashboardSagas() {
  yield all([call(fetchDashboardSaga)]);
}
```

// app.js

```
import { dashboardStart } from './redux/actions/dashboard';

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(dashboardStart());
  }, [dispatch]);
  return (
    // some dom
  );
}
```

// Action definition

```
import { DASHBAORD } from '../types/dashboard';

const dashboardStart = () => {
  return {
    type: DASHBAORD.START,
  };
};

const DashboardSuccess = (param) => {
  return {
    type: DASHBAORD.SUCCESS,
    payload: param,
  };
};

const DashboardFail = (param) => {
  return {
    type: DASHBAORD.FAILED,
    payload: param,
  };
};

export { dashboardStart, DashboardSuccess, DashboardFail };
```

Thank you

Comment: I used your code pretty much as is, and it works. The problem is somewhere else. See https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions62488823redux-saga-is-not-triggering-when-action-type-is-dispatched-t8tj2?file=/src/sagas/dashboard-sagas.js

Comment: Thanks for testing it out. I have no idea where else the issue can be. Any suggestions?

Comment: @MartinKadlec Found the issue. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. It was some weird glitch with the compose function in the store.js for redux. I removed that and installed the redux-devtools-extension library. Working fine now.

```
   // before
   compose(
     window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
       window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
     applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
   )

   // after
   composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
```

Answer (score -1):

If the actions is dispatched properly then the problem lies in the registration of your sagas.
Try replacing this code block

```js
function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([call(dashboardSagas)]);
}
```

with:

```js
function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
   // manually call the sagas. Only watcher functions. example: 
   dashboardSagas.saga1(), 
   dashboardSagas.saga2() 
  ]);
}
```